# useEffect timing with a while loop

Tags: reactjs

In below code snippet, why is 2 logged after 3 & 4? I'm confused because if without the while loop, 2 would be logged before 3 & 4.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function App() {
  const [state] = useState(0)
  console.log(1)
  
  const start = Date.now()
  while (Date.now() - start < 50) {
    window.timestamp = Date.now()
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2)
  }, [state])

  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(3))

  setTimeout(() => console.log(4), 0)

  return null
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App/>)
```

The correct log sequence is

```
1
3
4
2
```

[See code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-worker-f4ymwh?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: That's interesting. If the loop condition is ```Math.random() * 100 > 3```, the order most of the time is ```1 2 3 4```,  but sometimes it becomes ```1 3 4 2```. The same code produces different order (sometimes) if there is Math.random() or Date.now() inside the loop. That's strange

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `useEffect` is fired after the component is mounted

So the sequence of the actions is:

1. Render component
2. `console.log(1)` // => 1
3. Resolved `Promise` // => 3
4. That timeout that wait `0` millisecond and fire // => 4
5. And in the very end when component mounted fires `useEffect` // => 2

More info about `useEffect` can be found [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect)

Comment: If without the while loop, the logs will be 1,2,3,4 so your explanation cannot be true

Answer (score 0):

In the given code, the "2" is logged after "3" and "4" because the while loop blocks the main thread, delaying the execution of asynchronous code like promises and timeouts. Once the loop completes, these asynchronous tasks execute in the order they were queued, with "2" being logged last. Since **useEffect(() => console.log(2), [state])** registers an effect to log "2" when the state variable changes. However, since the state doesn't change and the thread is blocked by the while loop, this effect is not executed yet.

Comment: I'm confused about why useEffect runs after the asynchronous tasks once the while loop completes? I mean, why does useEffect run before the async tasks without the while loop?